# Srping boot save entity in session and retrieve

Tags: spring, session

I want to save logged user in a session and retrieve the user from the session. I am using spring boot

In user bean

```
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class User{
```

In the service layer, once login authentication is done, I save it in session

```
session.setAttribute("User", user);
```

and 
Autowire session

```
@Autowire
HttpSession session;
```

and I try to retrieve it another bean

```
 @Transient
 @Autowired
 private User user ;

@CreatedBy
protected User createdBy = user;
```

I am getting null. There is no value in the session.

Am I mission something.

Comment: Can you check by adding property spring.session.store-type=jdbc in your application.properties

Comment: The `another` bean isn't a Spring managed bean so that simply won't work. Also I wonder are you using Spring Security if so there are better (and other) ways of doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not using spring-session-JDBC or spring security.